# How to query WordPress database with Left Join

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I am trying to pull information about business listings from a wordpress database. The information is stored in the wp_posts table and the wp_postmeta table where all of the additional business information is listed.

The wp_postmeta table saves data like this: each piece of data has it's own row, the information is not stored as a serialized array all in one row.

Here is my database query so far:

```
$wpdb->get_results(
    " SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->posts    . 
    " LEFT JOIN "     . $wpdb->postmeta . 
    " ON "            . $wpdb->posts    . ".ID = " . $wpdb->postmeta . ".POST_ID" . 
    " WHERE "         . $wpdb->posts    . ".POST_TYPE = 'lv_listing' " .
    " AND "           . $wpdb->posts    . ".POST_STATUS = 'publish' " . 
    " GROUP BY "      . $wpdb->posts    . ".ID");
```

Currently, each set of results gives me only one row from the wp_postmeta table, where I am expecting like 20 rows that should match the ID I am grouping by.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So if you are seeing all of the fields from each table and nothing in the `wp_postmeta` table fields ( nothing other than null values), it is likely that you aren't matching anything in your join via the ON statement `wp_post.ID=wp_postmeta.POST_ID`.

Comment: Also, that group by at the end is against the sql standards, and luckily the recent versions of mysql do not allow such queries under the default settings any longer.

Comment: Did you getting me on answer?

Comment: So let me restate this. The results currently pull every column from the wp_posts table, and only one row from the wp_postmeta table, not all the rows that match the post_id in question.

Comment: Ah. I don't know what the data looks like in each of those tables but I think you want a `full join`. Give it a go.

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding ,can you execute a query in the MySQL database and check if the Data is coming as per your req or not in the database .

Below is the syntax of the left outer join

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Comment: He could just do an IN statement to see if there were actually any results. What you put up is exactly what he is already doing.
`SELECT *  FROM table1 WHERE ID IN ( SELECT POST_ID FROM table2  ) `